# Which Android SDK Packages do I need for Cordova and Android 4+

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdk-2.3

I installed cordova and all the required things. Now I have to choose in the Android Sdk Manager which packages I want to install. I want to make the App working for Android 4 and above. I have installed SDK Platform API 14 (ANDROID 4.0) and SDK Platform API 24 (ANDROID 7.0). Do I need more because I also want to cover all the version between this range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this: cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android